# Wrapper for functional object to change argument and return value types

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I want to write C++ class (let type name will be Adapter), which accepts function pointers or functional objects (especially, lambda functions) in constructor and stores it's by value internally (as std::function for exampl). After the class been constructed, it represents functional object too and acts just as wrapper for internal functional object. But with following conditions:

1. return type for wrapper-class (Adapter) is always predefined (let it be ReturnType);
2. but internal functor may have no return value -- in this case some DefaultValue substituted;
3. wrapper class always receives some ArgType as argument to operator();
4. but internal function may receive ArgType as argument too, or may not accept arguments at all -- in latter case it just should be called without arguments.

First question -- it's possible at all with C++11, and second quastion how can I do it? I have no idea where should I start.

I need deduce (in template) return value of functional object?  First pitfall, is  that std::result_of doesn't support function pointers. And I have no idea how can I deduce argument type (it may be empty, no arguments, or ArgType) for functional object (I know how it is possible for function pointers, via templated structure, but how can I do it for functional object?).

I need something like this:

```
template <typename Functor?> class Adapter
{
private:
    std::function<Void_or_ReturnType (Void_or_ArgType)> f;

public:
    template <typename Functor?> Adapter(const Functor& f) { ??? }

    ReturnType operator()(ArgType arg)
    {
         // one of the following four variants:
         return f(arg);
         f(arg); return DefaultValue;
         return f();
         f(); return DefaultValue;
  }
};
```

May be I need to deduce Void_or_ReturnType and Void_or_ArgType types in template and write different template specialization for operator() for each of four cases. But how exactly can I do this?

Comment: Do you specifically want C++11, or newer versions would work too?

Comment: You can check whether the parameter list is empty and whether the return type is void with SFINAE. From there, you can select one of the four variants you mentioned with tag dispatch. Probably you should tag dispatch in the constructor, to wrap your function into an appropriate lambda, to store it in `std::function<ReturnType(ArgType)> f`.

Answer (score 0):

I spent several hours on that and found some solution:
http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/628b8971466fa74d

Not sure, if this is good solution. May be someone suggest me, how can I minimize this code.

I copy source code here just in case (I updated source on coliru.stacked-crooked.com, here is old version, please see link above):

```cpp
#include <functional>
#include <stdio.h>

// functors
template<class T, class Yes, class No> struct IsArgs   { typedef typename IsArgs  <decltype(&T::operator()), Yes, No>::type type; };
template<class T, class Yes, class No> struct IsResult { typedef typename IsResult<decltype(&T::operator()), Yes, No>::type type; };

// function pointers
template<class R, class Yes, class No, typename ...Args> struct IsArgs   <R (*)(Args...), Yes, No>    { typedef Yes type; };
template<class R, class Yes, class No>                   struct IsArgs   <R (*)(), Yes, No>           { typedef No  type; };
template<class Yes, class No, class R, typename ...Args> struct IsResult <R (*)(Args...), Yes, No>    { typedef Yes type; };
template<class Yes, class No, typename ...Args>          struct IsResult <void (*)(Args...), Yes, No> { typedef No  type; };

// for function refs
template<class R, class Yes, class No, typename ...Args>    struct IsArgs  <R (Args...), Yes, No>     { typedef Yes type; };
template<class R, class Yes, class No>                      struct IsArgs  <R (), Yes, No>            { typedef No  type; };
template<class Yes, class No, typename R, typename ...Args> struct IsResult <R (Args...), Yes, No>    { typedef Yes type; };
template<class Yes, class No, typename ...Args>             struct IsResult <void (Args...), Yes, No> { typedef No  type; };

// for member pointers (lambdas, functors)
template<class T, class Yes, class No, class R, typename ...Args> struct IsArgs   <R (T::*)(Args...) const, Yes, No>    { typedef Yes type; };
template<class T, class Yes, class No, class R>                   struct IsArgs   <R (T::*)() const, Yes, No>           { typedef No  type; };
template<class T, class Yes, class No, class R, typename ...Args> struct IsResult <R (T::*)(Args...) const, Yes, No>    { typedef Yes type; };
template<class T, class Yes, class No, typename ...Args>          struct IsResult <void (T::*)(Args...) const, Yes, No> { typedef No  type; };

template <typename Retval, Retval Default, typename ...Args> class Adapter
{
    struct Noargs {
        std::function<Retval ()> func;
        template <typename F> Noargs(const F& f) : func(f) {}
        Retval operator()(Args...) { return func(); }
    };

    struct Noreturn {
        std::function<void (Args...)> func;
        template <typename F> Noreturn(const F& f) : func(f) {}
        Retval operator()(Args...args) { return func(args...), Default; }
    };

    struct Noretargs {
        std::function<void ()> func;
        template <typename F> Noretargs(const F& f) : func(f) {}
        Retval operator()(Args...) { return func(), Default; }
    };

    std::function<Retval (Args...args)> func;

public:
    template <typename Functor> Adapter(const Functor &f)
        : func(typename IsArgs<Functor,
                typename IsResult<Functor, std::function<Retval (Args...)>, Noreturn>::type, 
                typename IsResult<Functor, Noargs, Noretargs>::type>::type(f)) {}

    Retval operator()(Args...args) const { return func(args...); }
};




void deaf_silent_f() { puts("deaf/silent"); }
void silent_f(const char *arg) { printf("silent %s\n", arg); }
const char *deaf_f() { puts("deaf"); return "deaf"; }
const char *normal_f(const char *arg) { printf("normal %s\n", arg); return "normal"; }

const char Default[] = "DEFAULT";

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{    
    typedef Adapter<const char*, Default, const char*> A;

    {
      puts("function refs");
      A ds(deaf_silent_f); printf("-> %s\n", ds("ds"));
      A s(silent_f); printf("-> %s\n", s("s"));
      A d(deaf_f); printf("-> %s\n", d("d"));
      A n(normal_f); printf("-> %s\n", n("n"));
      puts("");
    }

    {
      puts("function pointers");
      A ds(&deaf_silent_f); printf("-> %s\n", ds("ds"));
      A s(&silent_f); printf("-> %s\n", s("s"));
      A d(&deaf_f); printf("-> %s\n", d("d"));
      A n(&normal_f); printf("-> %s\n", n("n"));
      puts("");
    }

    {
       puts("functors");
      A ds([=]{ printf("deaf/silent %d\n", argc); });         printf("-> %s\n", ds("ds"));
      A s([=](const char *a){ printf("silent(%s) %d\n", a, argc); });           printf("-> %s\n", s("s"));
      A d([=]{ printf("deaf %d\n", argc); return "deaf"; });  printf("-> %s\n", d("d"));
      A n([=](const char *a){ printf("normal(%s) %d\n", a, argc); return "normal";}); printf("-> %s\n", n("n"));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well ... what you ask isn't exactly trivial...

First of all: I don't think is a good idea take the default return value as template parameters: works for integer types but, for example, doesn't work for floating points types. You can go around this problem but I suggest to pass the default value as value in constructor.

Second: I suggest the following code to detect if a callable object of type `F` id callable with a given list of types

```
template <typename ...>
constexpr std::false_type isInvocableWithHelper (long);

template <typename F, typename ... Args>
constexpr auto isInvocableWithHelper (int)
   -> decltype( std::declval<F>()
                   (std::forward<Args>(std::declval<Args>())...),
                std::true_type{} );

template <typename F, typename ... Args>
using isInvocableWith = decltype(isInvocableWithHelper<F, Args...>(0));
```

Now, using delegating constructors and tag-dispatching, your `Adapter` constructor can be

```
  template <typename F>
  Adapter (F const & f, RetT defVal = RetT{})
     : Adapter{f, defVal, isInvocableWith<F, Args...>{},
               isInvocableWith<F>{}}
   { }
```

where the third argument (`isInvocableWith<F, Args...>{}`) is true (`std::true_type`) only if an `F` object is invocable with a list of `Args...` objects and the fourth argument (`isInvocableWith<F>{}`) is true (`std::true_type`) only if an `F` object is invocable without argument.

Now you have to detect if `F` (an object of type `F`) return `void` or a value (presumably a `RetT` or something convertible to `RetT`).

You can use again delegating constructors and tag-dispatching with

```
  template <typename F>
  Adapter (F const & f, RetT const & defVal, std::true_type const &,
           std::false_type const &)
   : Adapter{f, defVal, std::true_type{}, std::false_type{},
             std::is_same<void,
                decltype(f(std::forward<Args>(std::declval<Args>())...))>{}}
   { }
```

in case of callable with `Args...` arguments (observe that the last arguments is `std::true_type` (inherit from `std::true_type`) if `f` return `void`).

In case of `f` callable without arguments, the constructor become

```
  template <typename F>
  Adapter (F const & f, RetT const & defVal, std::false_type const &,
           std::true_type const &)
   : Adapter{f, defVal, std::false_type{}, std::true_type{},
             std::is_same<void, decltype(f())>{}}
   { }
```

Now the four final constructors

```
  template <typename F>
  Adapter (F const & f, RetT const & defVal, std::true_type const &,
           std::false_type const &, std::true_type const &)
     : defV{defVal}
   {
     func = [&, this](Args && ... as)
      { f(std::forward<Args>(as)...); return defV; };

     std::cout << "--- case 1 (full, void)" << std::endl;
   }

  template <typename F>
  Adapter (F const & f, RetT const &, std::true_type const &,
           std::false_type const &, std::false_type const &)
   {
     func = [&](Args && ... as)
      { return f(std::forward<Args>(as)...); };

     std::cout << "--- case 2 (full, RetT)" << std::endl;
   }

  template <typename F>
  Adapter (F const & f, RetT const & defVal, std::false_type const &,
           std::true_type const &, std::true_type const &)
     : defV{defVal}
   {
     func = [&, this](Args && ...)
      { f(); return defV; };

     std::cout << "--- case 3 (noArgs, void)" << std::endl;
   }

  template <typename F>
  Adapter (F const & f, RetT const &, std::false_type const &,
           std::true_type const &, std::false_type const &)
   {
     func = [&](Args && ...)
      { return f(); };

     std::cout << "--- case 4 (noArgs, RetT)" << std::endl;
   }
```

Observe that, in all cases, I've constructed a lambda function that receive a `Args...` list of arguments and use it only if appropriate.

I understand that is a little complicated but the following is the example in your answer modified according this solution.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

template <typename ...>
constexpr std::false_type isInvocableWithHelper (long);

template <typename F, typename ... Args>
constexpr auto isInvocableWithHelper (int)
   -> decltype( std::declval<F>()
                   (std::forward<Args>(std::declval<Args>())...),
                std::true_type{} );

template <typename F, typename ... Args>
using isInvocableWith = decltype(isInvocableWithHelper<F, Args...>(0));

template <typename RetT, typename ... Args>
class Adapter
 {
   private:
      std::function<RetT(Args ...)> func;

      RetT  defV { RetT{} };

      template <typename F>
      Adapter (F const & f, RetT const & defVal, std::true_type const &,
               std::false_type const &, std::true_type const &)
         : defV{defVal}
       {
         func = [&, this](Args && ... as)
          { f(std::forward<Args>(as)...); return defV; };

         std::cout << "--- case 1 (full, void)" << std::endl;
       }

      template <typename F>
      Adapter (F const & f, RetT const &, std::true_type const &,
               std::false_type const &, std::false_type const &)
       {
         func = [&](Args && ... as)
          { return f(std::forward<Args>(as)...); };

         std::cout << "--- case 2 (full, RetT)" << std::endl;
       }

      template <typename F>
      Adapter (F const & f, RetT const & defVal, std::false_type const &,
               std::true_type const &, std::true_type const &)
         : defV{defVal}
       {
         func = [&, this](Args && ...)
          { f(); return defV; };

         std::cout << "--- case 3 (noArgs, void)" << std::endl;
       }

      template <typename F>
      Adapter (F const & f, RetT const &, std::false_type const &,
               std::true_type const &, std::false_type const &)
       {
         func = [&](Args && ...)
          { return f(); };

         std::cout << "--- case 4 (noArgs, RetT)" << std::endl;
       }

      template <typename F>
      Adapter (F const & f, RetT const & defVal, std::true_type const &,
               std::false_type const &)
       : Adapter{f, defVal, std::true_type{}, std::false_type{},
                 std::is_same<void,
                    decltype(f(std::forward<Args>(std::declval<Args>())...))>{}}
       { } 

      template <typename F>
      Adapter (F const & f, RetT const & defVal, std::false_type const &,
               std::true_type const &)
       : Adapter{f, defVal, std::false_type{}, std::true_type{},
                 std::is_same<void, decltype(f())>{}}
       { }

   public:
      template <typename F>
      Adapter (F const & f, RetT defVal = RetT{})
         : Adapter{f, defVal, isInvocableWith<F, Args...>{},
                   isInvocableWith<F>{}}
       { }

      template <typename ... As>
      RetT operator() (As && ... as) const
       { return func(std::forward<As>(as)...); }
 };

void deaf_silent_f ()
 { puts("deaf/silent"); }

void silent_f (char const * arg)
 { printf("silent %s\n", arg); }

char const * deaf_f ()
 { puts("deaf"); return "deaf"; }

char const * normal_f (char const * arg)
 { printf("normal %s\n", arg); return "normal"; }

int main ()
 {    
   typedef Adapter<char const *, char const *> A;

    {
      puts("function refs");
      A ds(deaf_silent_f, "Def1"); printf("-> %s\n", ds("ds"));
      A s(silent_f, "Def2"); printf("-> %s\n", s("s"));
      A d(deaf_f); printf("-> %s\n", d("d"));
      A n(normal_f); printf("-> %s\n", n("n"));
      puts("");
    }

    {
      puts("function pointers");
      A ds(&deaf_silent_f, "Def3"); printf("-> %s\n", ds("ds"));
      A s(&silent_f, "Def4"); printf("-> %s\n", s("s"));
      A d(&deaf_f); printf("-> %s\n", d("d"));
      A n(&normal_f); printf("-> %s\n", n("n"));
      puts("");
    }

    {
      puts("functors");
      A ds([=]{ printf("deaf/silent %d\n", 42); }, "Def5");
      printf("-> %s\n", ds("ds"));
      A s([=](char const * a){ printf("silent(%s) %d\n", a, 42); }, "Def6");
      printf("-> %s\n", s("s"));
      A d([=]{ printf("deaf %d\n", 42); return "deaf"; });
      printf("-> %s\n", d("d"));
      A n([=](char const * a){ printf("normal(%s) %d\n", a, 42);
                               return "normal";});
      printf("-> %s\n", n("n"));
    }
 }
```

Comment: You don't need to accept `bool_constant`s by reference.

Comment: If the callable can be called as both `f(args...)` and `f()`, you don't wrap it as *either*. This is probably for the best, as accepting that case will surprise *someone*

Comment: I'd be tempted to store `defV` as a `std::optional<RetT>` (or `unique_ptr`), so that you don't fail with a non-default constructable `RetT`

Comment: @Caleth - `bool_constant`'s: why not by reference? Callable in both way: I don't know what to do in this case but, if the OP know what to do, it's easy to add a second-level constructor to implement the case (if he want to). `std::optional`: not available (the question is tagged C++11, not C++17). Anyway, I suppose that this example has a lot of troubles (the forwarding management is correct? Not sure) but is mainly to give the idea.